# Where are the traces connected to RESET-EN leading?

Tags: arduino-mega

Once again, I am following [this schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560_R3-sch.pdf), and I am confused as to where RESET-EN connects:

[image]

This is how I have it mocked up it Fritzing, but I feel like this is incorrect:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the DTR output of the ATmega16u2 which is connected to RESET pin of the ATmega2560 for reset by avrdude over DTR signal before upload of the sketch. There is a trace by default. Cutting the trace disables the auto-reset. Soldering a bridge on  RESET-EN pads re-enables the auto-reset.

[image]

the schematics part you quoted in question misses the long unconnected line for the RESET label. It leads here:

[image]

Comment: So this connects RESET to gnd?

Comment: not directly. this enables the USB chip (an ATmega16u2 with a firmware) to pull-down the reset pin of the ATmega2560.

Comment: So where does the other side of the trace connect in the diagram linked above?

Comment: I enhanced the answer

Comment: Ah, so the reset pin of the Atmega 2560 is connected to the reset pin of the Atmega16u2?

Comment: And also doesn't the 16u2 come loaded with firmware or would I have to flash it myself via ICSP?

Comment: The DTR output from the 16U2 is used to Reset the 328P, 2560, etc.  The 16U2 runs the USB interface program, which can be found in one of the Arduino folders.

Comment: Again, so are the reset pins of the Atmega 2560 and the 16u2 connected?

Comment: if the reset were connected the 16u2 would reset itself too while resetting the 2560.

Comment: So then where does the RESET pin of the 2560 go, and where does the RESET pin of the 16u2 go?

Comment: @3ddavies a line with a loose end and a label in electrical schematics goes to other line(s) with a loose end with the same label

Comment: to me that would mean that the two reset pins are attatched.

Comment: RESET pin of 16u2 has a line labeled RESET2